# how to echo content of nodes inclusing html tags using php domdocument

Tags: php, domdocument, dom-node

I have a Domnodelist of html nodes, which I would like to echo out including their html tags so that I can apply a regex.When I do:

```
            foreach ($nodeList as $key => $node) {
               echo $node->nodeValue;
            }
```

I get only the text portions of the nodes, without html tags.

when I try:

echo $node->saveHTML;

I get the error: Undefined property: DOMElement::$saveHTML

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance,

Bill

Comment: is the code is working for you?

Comment: This part of the code is now working  - Thanks jhonraymos

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`saveHTML`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) is a function, so you need to call it (you were missing the parens). It's also part of `DOMDocument`; the node will be passed in as a parameter.

So the correct form is:

```
echo $document->saveHTML($node);
```

Important note: `saveHTML` only supports a parameter from PHP 5.3.6 onwards.

However, people use `DOMDocument` specifically so that they can process it *without* resorting to regular expressions. It seems that here you are trying to do the opposite. If so, reconsider your approach -- regular expressions are a hacky way to process HTML that will bring trouble the second you decide to do anything that is not totally trivial.